# recursive trailing return types visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++11

I've just upgraded to vc++ 2010 express from 2008 in order to make use of the c++11 features but I'm having problems using trailing return types in a recursive overloaded operator. I want to take two std::vectors with an arbitrary number of dimensions and add the elements to give a new vector. However I want to be able to allow vectors of ints to be added to vectors of doubles etc and automatically get the right return type - this requires a trailing return type. Here is the minimal code that reproduces the error and does something usefull.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<class T, class U>
inline auto operator+(const std::vector<T> &a, const std::vector<U> &b) 
-> std::vector<decltype(T()+U())>
{
    std::vector<decltype(T()+U())> result;
    result.resize(std::min(a.size(),b.size()));
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<result.size(); ++i) result[i]=a[i]+b[i];
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > mydoublevect2d(1);
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > myintvect2d(1);
    mydoublevect2d.resize(1);
    myintvect2d.resize(1);
    mydoublevect2d[0].push_back(1.0);
    myintvect2d[0].push_back(1);
    decltype(mydoublevect2d+myintvect2d) myothervect2d;
    myothervect2d=mydoublevect2d+myintvect2d;
    std::cout << myothervect2d[0][0];
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately this crashes the compiler and generates the following error

```
fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
1>  (compiler file 'msc1.cpp', line 1420)
1>   To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
1>  Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++ 
1>   Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
```

In fact even the following main function causes the same crash and error

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > mydoublevect2d;
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > myintvect2d;
    decltype(mydoublevect2d+myintvect2d) myothervect2d;
    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles and runs fine on gcc 4.6.1. I've tried changing from operator+ to a function called add, but this causes the same crash. Using this function with 1d vecters works fine so it has something to do with the recursion, i.e this works

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<double> mydoublevect;
    std::vector<int> myintvect;
    mydoublevect.push_back(1.0);
    myintvect.push_back(1);
    decltype(mydoublevect+myintvect) myothervect=mydoublevect+myintvect;
    return 0;
}
```

Has anyone come accross similar problems and/or found a solution?

Phil

Comment: It's a compiler bug, [report it](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/).

Comment: Thanks for the bug report link, I have reported it. It would still be good to hear if anyone else has hit the same bug and/or found a workaround

Comment: [Here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/723213/) is the bug link if anyone else cares to vote it up.